# Computing $\Sigma_{n\ge3}^\infty\frac{n}{(n^2-n-1).\ln{n}.(\ln{(\ln{n})})^a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've tried applying Raabe's, d'Alembert's and Cauchy's (root) convergence test but none of them get me very far.

I also thought about trying Cauchy's integral convergence test but integrating this function doesn't really seem possible.

Finally I tried applying the quotient convergence test by comparing with $x_n=n$, but that doesn't give me a result either.

I don't really know what else I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: For $a\gt 1$, note that after a while $n^2-n-1\gt n^2/2$. Use the  Integral Test replacing $n^2-n-1$ by $n^2/2$ to conclude convergence.

Use $n^2-n-1\lt n^2$ and the Integral Test to conclude divergence for $a\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First using the asymptotic comparison test the given series has the same nature of the series

$$\sum\frac{1}{n\ln n(\ln(\ln n))^a}$$
and then using the Cauchy condensation test this series is equivalent to
$$\sum \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^a}$$
which is convergent if and only if $a>1$ using the integral test.